# DateFormat on DisplayFor not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've set the Data Annotation for date, it works when I use the EditorFor but when I use the DisplayFor it is not working.
The date is come from a collection of data. I get this format 8/13/2011 12:00:00 AM instead of 8/13/2011. What is wrong with the code.

**Data Annotation for Date**

```
    [DisplayName("Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")] 
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date required.")]
    public DateTime EM_Date { get; set; }
```

**View Code**

```
@foreach (EventViewModel item in Model)
{
    <tr>
         <td class="AdBoxBodyRow1" style="text-align: center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EM_Date) </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Tell us about the public object EM_Date?

Comment: well, it is a field having a date datatype.

Comment: *Date datatype*? Where did you saw this type? All I can see is `object`.

Comment: did you tried the DisplayTemplate code? sample is added to my answer.

Comment: I soled it but in different approach. Thank you for the answer.